# UpdateCursor gives RuntimeError that column does not exist

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, cursor, python-script-tool, runtimeerror

I have managed to get my previous update cursor to work without any hiccups. All I have done is change the fields the script needs to look for. The error I am getting is:

> RuntimeError: A column was specified that does not exist.

[image]

The column exists in the attribute table the runtime error is on line 52 of the script (for row in cursor) :
Here is the script

````
#Script to add in a new period field and base the values on the existing HER period column
import arcpy

#Adjust these two lines:
fc = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
fields = ['PeriodRang','PeriodFrom']

#Dictionary of old and new value. Add all your values here, instead of many if/elifs
remap = {
    'Palaeolithic':'Palaeolithic',
    'Later Prehistoric':'Prehistoric',
    'Prehistoric':'Prehistoric',
    'Mesolithic':'Mesolithic',
    'Late Mesolithic to Late Bronze Age':'Mesolithic',
    'Neolithic':'Neolithic',
    'modern':'Modern',
    'Unknown':'Undated',
    'Undated':'Undated'
    }

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] in remap: #row[0] is the value of periodRang field. This if, is checking whether the value exist in the remap dictionary
            row[1] = remap[row[0]]
            cursor.updateRow(row) ```
````

Comment: Add `arcpy.Exists(fc)` and `arcpy.ListFields(fc)` (with case-insensitive comparison with `fields`) validation to your script.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the error by ticking the store relative path names in the properties.